# Pi2 Flashing Green Light Only

Tags: pi-2, power, boot-issues

My Pi2 no longer boots. I just get a steady flashing green light. No obvious pattern, just continuously flashing every second or so. No red light.

It's connected to an official power supply like this: https://www.pi-supply.com/product/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply-5v-2a-microusb

This is what happened. It's connected to a HDMI to VGA adapter like this one: http://www.kenable.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=6824

I decided I'd like to use the audio from it too, so connected it to power (it has a power port) to allow this. Unfortunately I did this with the Pi powered on. It went off and the result is the green flashing lights.

I've tried reflashing the image. Removing all other connected USB devices tested other power sources. No joy. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you check your LED flashing pattern against what is described [here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern) does any fit?

Comment: What is the audio device you mention?  What voltage power does it use and how is the audio device connected to the Pi?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a break in pattern. Just continuous flashing.

Comment: The VGA adapter I linked to has a 3.5mm audio jack as well as a mini-USB power socket. So it's connected via HDMI. It's not clear what power it uses, but the adapter has an active IC chip so it needs power for some compatibility. In hindsight. It appears to have upset the Pi.

Comment: It is a steady flashing, though?  Is the red PWR led on?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, steady flashing green light, no red light.

Comment: Nobody have any ideas please?

Comment: Left it unplugged for a few days and still the same. Guessing it's dead.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Can anyone confirm it is dead?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. It's probably too late for you, but i found that switching out the power adapter fixed things promptly. I tried the faulty power adapter on another pi and had the same issue.